# Automation (Keyboard Maestro) running the process in the background without interfering on other activities

Tags: macos, virtualization, automation

Is there anyway I can do automation on the background while doing other activities in my Laptop?

I'm using Keyboard Maestro with recorded event, like mouse interaction to a form and looping from a datasource.

If I'm doing the automation I cannot do other stuff in my laptop because my mouse and other actions are being utilized by the Keyboard Maestro automation process. Is there I can split my window (like virtual machine) without installing a new Mac OSX? probably just a small software that will virtually give me an option have 2 windows running without interfering the other one.

or else i think I'll have to install Mac OSX in my VMWare just to run the automation process.

Any thoughts?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly VNC to your local host and login as another user.

See [This AppleInsider link](http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/03/31/mac_os_x_10_7_lion_to_introduce_multi_user_screen_sharing.html)